# PHP session variable not delivering correctly

Tags: php, session, scope

I am having trouble understanding this logic:

I am using JavaScript to detect the browser width and passing that value to PHP as a session variable using the following code.

```
<?php
    session_start()
    if (empty($_SESSION['layoutType'])) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> var session=false; var layoutType;</script>';
    } else {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> var session=true; var layoutType=' . $_SESSION['layoutType'] . ';</script>';
    }
    if (!empty($_SESSION['layoutType'])) {
        $layoutType = $_SESSION['layoutType'];
        if ( $layoutType <= 219 ) {
            $layout = 'mobile';
        } else if ($layoutType >= 220 && $layoutType <= 1024 ) {
            $layout = 'tablet';
        } else {
            $layout = 'desktop';
        }
    }
    echo $layout;
```

This correctly displays the value as `mobile` or `tablet` or `desktop` depending on the browser width. But when I try to use the same variable and paste the following code below the above code, it changes the value of `$layout`:

```
    function getFevicons(){
        if ( $layout = 'mobile' ); {
            echo '
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="cdn/images/apple-touch-icon.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="cdn/images/apple-touch-icon-72.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="cdn/images/apple-touch-icon-114.png">
            ';
        }
        echo $layout;
    }
?>
```

Even though the layout is for the desktop, it now gives the output as `mobile` and also it echos the above [favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) links. Why?

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you might want to rename `getFevicons` to `getFavicons`. :) Not really related to your issue though.

Comment: @Christian sorry for the typo and thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your function like so (`getFevicons($layout);`):

```
function getFevicons($layout){
    switch ($layout) {
        case 'mobile':
            echo '<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="cdn/images/apple-touch-icon.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="cdn/images/apple-touch-icon-72.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="cdn/images/apple-touch-icon-114.png">';
            break;

        case 'desktop':
            echo 'whatever';
            break;

        case 'tablet':
            echo 'whatever';
            break;

        default:
            // This will absolutely do nothing
    }
    echo $layout;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your function introduces a new [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Variables outside a function are not visible inside the function. You have to [pass them as parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php):

```
function getFevicons($layout){
    ...
    echo $layout;
}
```

And the call your function as:

```
getFevicons($layout);
```

---

You could also use the [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) keyword, but that is generally considered bad practice, because it leads to a code base that is harder to maintain and dependencies are unclear.

```
function getFevicons(){
    global $layout;
    ...
    echo $layout;
}
```

Comment: He could use this `global $layout`.

Comment: @AhmedJolani No he should not. That quickly leads to bad, unmaintainable code. Should be avoided.

Comment: Frankly I really don't know who did this, I am really sorry.

Comment: @AhmedJolani It's quite strange. I solved the problem, provided a quality (at least I think) answer that tries to teach. I have no problem with you, you just helped the OP, who was unwilling to do anything on his own. Even though the question had nothing to do with `switch` and conditions. I'd just want to know the reasons for the downvote because I'm interested whether I could improve my answer. Hate-downvoting has no place on a professional site.

Comment: Here is an Upvote first, don't worry those spammers are mindless.

Comment: @AhmedJolani Hehe, thanks for the upvote, but it's not about the points. I have enough :).